# jQuery - multiple event listeners for same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an button with an id:

`<input id='someButton' />`

I want to attach an event listener on this button:

```
$('#form').on('click', '#someButton', function() { 
   alert("My listener called");
```

});

However, unbeknownst to me, someone previously wrote an event listener for this very same button:

```
$('#form').on('click', '#someButton', function() { 
   alert("Some other listener called"); 
});
```

I encountered some code that effectively does the same thing as above, and it seems like the first listener registered is the one that is used.  Am I correct in assuming jQuery will always call the first event listener registered on a specific id (and *only* that listener)?

Comment: nope. in jquery you can add multiple event listeners..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incorrect. jQuery will call ALL event listeners bound to an element, in the order they were bound.

To remove an existing event handler, use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('#form').off('click'); // click event handler(s) removed
$('#form').off(); // all event handler(s) removed
```

Be aware that events delegated from ancestor DOM elements won't be removed this way, though.

Comment: For completeness, if one of the handlers invokes [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) on the event, the handlers further down the chain will not be called. It might be the cause of the behavior observed by the questioner.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out both handlers were actually being called.  Just an oversight on my part.  No call was made to stopImmediatePropagation(), but that is useful knowledge to have!

Answer (score 0):

you could use mousedown:

```
$('#form').on('mousedown', '#someButton', function() { 
    alert("My listener called"); 
});
```

Hope this help.